# interfaces and DB

Tags: java, database, interface

I have code like this and this is pure java class which does not involve and DB Connections

```
    if(transfer.getAmount().getDestination().getCountryCode().equals("CN"){
        transfer.getBankDetails().setCountryCode("CN");
        transfer.setDeliveryOptions(null);
        return new Event(this, "D2B");
    }else if(transfer.getAmount().getDestination().getCountryCode().equals("US"){
        transfer.getBankDetails().setCountryCode("CN");
        transfer.setDeliveryOptions(null);
        return new Event(this, "D2B");
    }
```

and this code repeats for all the countries now I want optimize the code.

For that I have a table which has country name and country table.
So I want to get the country code from DB and reduce most of the code.

Comment: You should elaborate a bit. As is, it looks to me you could just use the last 3 lines unconditionally.

Comment: for transfer interface we are setting amount and from that we are getting destination and country code from destination all these are interfaces and by using .equals we are comparing the returned code with country code hard coded from the page label.but i have a country table and code table in DB so will be get the particular code without hardcoding it in pagelables

Comment: OK. Then put them in a HashMap and look them up. I still have the feeling I am missing something. Even now, you can move the identical code outside the if bodies.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashMap<String, String>` in which you will insert your list of countries. Then you just need to call you code once, like

```
String aCountryCode = transfer.getAmount().getDestination().getCountryCode();
String aBankCountryCode = aMapOfCountries.get(aCountryCode );

if (aBankCountryCode != null) {
  transfer.getBankDetails().setCountryCode(aBankCountryCode );
}
```